# Unused import statement "import android .support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a sliding menu that uses fragments, each fragment activity are extending Fragment. One of the activities, **Slider_Fragment2.java** needs to import the **android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity**. The problem is, it kept on appearing as unused.

Here's my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

*I removed the appcompat library in the module settings and added it again, they're the same version of my support library.

*Clean and build the project

*Checked the libs folder of my project and looked for android-support-v4.jar for deletion, but I have none.

*Changed the declaration of my class to **Slider_Fragment2 extends AppCompatActivty**, this removed the errors in the activity but another appeared in my **MainActivity** where I have a function, **replaceFragment()** requiring the activities to extend Fragment only.

**Here's my replaceFragment()**:

```
private void replaceFragment(int pos){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(pos){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment4();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment5();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment6();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment7();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Slider_Fragment1();
            break;
    }

    if(null!=fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: How could you extend `AppCompatActivity` to a `Fragment` ?

Comment: Why did you look for `android-support-v4.jar` when the unused import is for the `v7` library?

Comment: that's what I want to know, is it possible? @Wizard

Answer (score 0):

Remove the stated import statements first. If it is really required, the Classes that need it will get highlighted. Take your cursor to the erroring Class references and press **Alt+Enter** and then select `import...`. It will get the right packages and add imports.

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicate dependency
<strike>`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'`</strike>
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

Use same version number for all `com.android.support` libs, `23.1.1` is the latest for today.
After that, optimize imports if needed.

Comment: thank you sir, i have removed and replaced it with the proper dependencies. But still the errors are there

Comment: I think, you have to show a code of problematic fragment with error message. BTW, unused import is not an error, it is a warning.